# jQuery .live() events in a widget in FF3

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a simple jQuery widget and I have the following two lines in the `_init()` method.

```
this.element.find("li.thumb img").css("cursor", "pointer");
this.element.find("li.thumb img").live("click", function() { alert(); });
```

The addition of the style property in the first line works in both `IE7` and `FF3`. However, the binding of the event in the second line only works in `IE7`, **not in** `FF3`.

Elements are dynamically added to the widget so I need to use the `.live()` method. I know I could combine these two lines, I'm just trying to get the basics working.

Any thoughts on how this may be occurring?

Comment: You do know the arguments to `alert()` are *not* optional in FF3? The click handler as you have it will actually throw an exception when executed (in FF3). Perhaps it is being bound just fine but throwing an error when fired?

Comment: Well, you learn something every day... No arguments to the alert() was the problem.